# React with webpack cannot find tsx component dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am adding Typescript support to an older React application. It was *not* created with create-react-app. I've installed typescript and ts-loader. I added a tsconfig file which allows js files. And I updated the webpack.config.json file to use ts-loader to handle ts and tsx files. But when I tried to convert a very simple component from .js to .tsx, it does not compile. I get the error:

```
"This dependency was not found:

* Components/Molecules/SectionA/ButtonBarFooter in ./src/components/Organisms/SectionA/Form.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save Components/Molecules/SectionA/ButtonBarFooter
```

I thought that maybe it had something to due with configuring aliases in our webpack config because Components is an alias. So I duplicated it into the tsConfig. But that has not fixed this error. Why can't ButtonBarFooter.tsx be found by the parent component on compile?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "Actions/*": ["actions/*"],
      "Components/*": ["components/*"],
      "Assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "Util/*": ["util/*"],
      "Routes/*": ["routes/*"],
      "Constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "Helpers/*": ["helpers/*"],
      "Api/*": ["api/*"]
      
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

webpack.config.json (resolve is commented out because when it was active, it couldn't find 35 modules, which were JS components!):

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Webpack Config
 */
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = (relativePath) => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

// plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
let pathsToClean = ['dist', 'build'];

// the clean options to use
let cleanOptions = {
  root: __dirname,
  verbose: false, // Write logs to console.
  dry: false,
};

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', 'react-hot-loader/patch', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: resolveApp('dist'),
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[hash:8].js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/index.js',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    compress: true,
    port: 9000, // port number
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  // resolve alias (Absolute paths)
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Actions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/actions/'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
      Util: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util/'),
      Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
      Constants: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
      Helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers/'),
      Api: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/api/'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          //loader: "source-map-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: '/',
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            },
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
      // Scss compiler
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            },
          },

          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  // resolve: {
  //   // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
  //   extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  // },
  performance: {
    hints: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warning' : false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      pathsToClean,
      cleanOptions,
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // all options are optional
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
      ignoreOrder: false, // Enable to remove warnings about conflicting order
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: What happens if you **temporarily** replace  the aliased imports with the full doted path `( ../../..)` ? If that works, we can proceed with our investigation by assuming that the issue is about alias resolution.

Comment: @exaucae You're right - even with the relative path replacing the aliased import, it still cannot find it. When I used the relative path, the error is "This relative module was not found." When I used the aliased path, the error is "This dependency was not found."